# Check if array value contains specific value in html

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a array in angularjs like below:

```
var test=["abc/1/1","def/2/2","efg/3/3"];
```

I want to check if an array contains value having "abc" in it in html

I checked:

```
test.indexOf("abc")!=-1
```

but its returning `false`

I have populated array in JS and i want to check if array contains value containing abc in html.

button form="myAttributeAdd" type="submit" data-ng-disabled="" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">  Save

This is button element in my html.
here data-ng-disabled will be true or false depending on array data.If array data value contains abc it will be enabled else disabled

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegExp to search abc inside it.

```js
//getting html value
var valueToFind = document.getElementById('htmlCode').innerText;

function findValue(findString) {
  //getting arrays to be find
  var test = ["abc/1/1", "def/2/2", "efg/3/3"];
  //creating the regex
  var reg = new RegExp(findString);
  
  //a.match will show the output
  console.log(findString,test.some(a => a.match(reg)))

  console.log(findString,test.filter(a => a.match(reg)))

}

//invoking the function
findValue('abc');
findValue(valueToFind);
```

```html
<div id="htmlCode">efg</div>
```

Comment: I have populated array in JS and i want to check if array contains value containing abc in html

Comment: Yes so you can replace your html value to `RegExp('abc')` and it should work. let me know if you find any difficulties.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more here

Comment: @SayaliDingankar Check my edit and comments you will understand

Comment: cant i do it in html

Comment: @SayaliDingankar please explain your input and expected output, I can not understand what you are trying tos ay

Comment: I have array in angularjs file and i want to use it in multiple htmls ...so i want to check if array value has specific value inside html to enable and disable certain buttons and not in js.

Comment: Add your example please

Comment: <button form="myAttributeAdd" type="submit"
                    data-ng-disabled=""
                    class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
                    <i class="fic glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Save
                   </button>

    here data-ng-disabled will be true or false depending on array data

Comment: this is not efficient you need to edit your question and then show us full example